# Nginx Vhost Bandwidth?

Tags: nginx, bandwidth, vhosts

So I'm trying to work out the throughput of each individual virtual host through nginx to see which sites are destroying bandwidth, however after a number of logging methods and munin plugins, I've come up with nothing.

Anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [Munin Byprojects](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/contrib/tree/master/plugins/nginx/nginx_byprojects) for that! It does exactly what you described.